# What does "line = s.gets" mean in this socket example?

Tags: ruby, sockets

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2000)

while line = s.gets # Read lines from socket
  puts line         # and print them
end

s.close             # close socket when done
```

I'm a newcomer to Ruby and sockets in general; I got this code from the Ruby Sockets documentation page as one of their examples. I understand everything except the `line = s.gets` snippet. When gets is called is it getting input or is a method of the class Socket? Can anyone please give me an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: The comment literally tells you what it does

Comment: Do you know what `foo.bar` does in Ruby? Then, what does `s.gets` do?

Comment: I understand the comment but I don't understand how the data us being read.

Comment: It is a method of the Socket class, and what that method does is get a line and assigns that line to the variable 'line'.

Comment: "is it getting input or is a method of the class Socket" why the "or"? `gets` is a method of the class from which `s` was instantiated **AND** the purpose of this method is to read lines from the socket.

Comment: [It is] getting input **AND** is a method of the class Socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from documentation can be explained as

> Open a TCP socket to localhost, port 2000.
>
> Read from it line by line; while reading print what was read.
>
> When there is no content left to read, close the socket.

Basically, I think the whole expression

```
while line = s.gets
  puts line
end
```

can be confusing for Ruby newcomers.

The code snippet above reads content from socket `s` with method `gets`. This [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-gets) returns a "line" (a string), including trailing symbol `\n`. That result is assigned to `line` variable.

`line = s.gets` expression is not a comparison as it may seem; it's assignment. Every assignment in Ruby returns a value, which is assigned. So the result of this operation is a string, returned by `gets`.

When evaluated by `while` statement, string is converted to `boolean`. Any string, even empty one, is considered as `true`, so block with `puts line` is executed.

Since it is a `while` loop, it will be repeated again and again, until `gets` method returns `nil`, which means there is nothing left to read from the socket (transfer complete).

Comment: You might want to note that the assignment `a = b` in Ruby is an expression whose value is `b`, this seems to be a common stumbling point for beginners. Thank you helping.

Comment: Thank you for the through explanation, but can you please clarify: "What is the difference for gets when used for getting input and gets when used for reading input/output? Thanks!

Comment: ```gets``` stands for 'get string'; it reads the next “line'' from the I/O stream. When you run it from irb-console it reads a string from standard IO-stream - ie waits for user input. When called as a method of ```TCPSocket``` object, it reads from that socket. So there is no too much difference - it gets string.

Comment: Please note also, that there are many realizations of ```gets```. When calling in irb console it is https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets . When called as a IO-object method it is https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-i-gets . Implementations are different, but semantics are the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 2000 # Opens a TCP connection to host


while line = s.gets # Read the socket like you read any IO object.
                    # If s.gets is nil the while loop is broken
      puts line     # Print the object (String or Hash or an object ...)
end
```

Its like :

Client side

```
#Init connection
   Client.send("Hello") #The client send the message over socket(TCP/IP)
#Close connection
```

Server side

```
#Init connection
    while line = s.gets # The client get the message sended by the client and store it in the variable line

        puts line  # => Hello
    end
#Close connection
```